# How to proxy requests to a localhost route to a non-local url

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, wamp, mod-rewrite

I am setting up a local environment for testing using WAMP.

The app (angular app) sits in the /wamp/www/app/ directory. It makes requests to another api by sending requests to another route on its same server. (Specifically to /wamp/www/api/route)

We have a dev api server that exists at http://api.com. We have another test instance of the angular app at http://testapp.com/app/ that can send requests to http://api.com by pointing at http://testapp.com/api/route.

The way that this works in the test instance (non local) is that we have a .htaccess file at http://testapp.com/api/route that takes requests to http://testapp.com/api/route/* and sends them to http://api.com/*

The .htaccess file that does this is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule (.*) http://api.com/$1 [NC,P]
</IfModule>
```

When I copy this .htaccess file to my /wamp/www/api/route/ directory I expect the following behavior:

***What I want***

The app will send a request to /wamp/www/api/route/stuff/ and the .htaccess file in /route/ takes that request, and proxies it to http://api.com/stuff

***What I get***

The app will send a request to /wamp/www/api/route/stuff/, and get a 404 back.

I've made sure that AllowOverride all is set, that the rewrite engine is on, and that mod-rewrite is enabled. I know the .htaccess file is being seen, because if I put garbage in it, i get a 500 instead of the 404, and my garbage gets into the log.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

---

After help from Purefan, I enabled rewrite logging, and since enabling, there have been no rewrite attempts, which would suggest that the rewrite rule is not ever being executed on the requests.

I have now tried to change the flow of how I call the rewrite rule.

I created a directory in the httpd config file, as follows:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/api/route">
    Options  +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteRule (.*) http://api.com/$1 [NC,P]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And I still get the same behavior

Comment: Remember that you are rewriting the request based on URIs, not on folders. When apache gets a request it matches it to a set of rules in the VirtualHost blocks, if the request matches one of the VirtualHost blocks then the rules in that block process the request. When the app sends a request to `localhost` maybe the block with DocumentRoot `/wamp/www/api/route/stuff` intercepts it, but maybe it doesnt. Check your access logs, set one different per VirtualHost to make it easier

Comment: You can also enable the [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to help you see what is being rewritten and how

Comment: The rewrite log sounds helpful. I'll look into this and check back in. Thanks!

Comment: A request is sent to the correct spot it would seem, but with the rewrite log on, nothing seems to be getting re-wrote ever.
[03/Feb/2017:11:02:01 -0500] "GET /api/route/stuff

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Purefan, with the rewrite log enabled, I saw that the rewrite was attempting to rewrite, but then the request was never sent.

When I removed the P flag from the RewriteRule, it would rewrite the request, but then my headers were not added, because we were not proxying, which I need to do.

This then lead me to realize that the proxy was not working correctly, which immediately let to this solution:

In the httpd.conf file, change

```
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

to

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

TL;DR

Enable mod_proxy if you want to proxy with the P flag on a re-write rule